# How can I create a poll system in an efficient way

Tags: c#, css, sql, asp.net, database

I have my code below in ASP that the Poll system retrieved data from SQL (count of each poll), but the way that I use it's not efficient. I want help to rewrite the same code in an efficient way.
I use a lot of **connect** ,**sqlDataReader** and **query**!!! i want to minimize all of them

C#

```
Connect con = new Connect();
Connect con1 = new Connect();
Connect con22 = new Connect();
Connect con3 = new Connect(); Connect con4 = new Connect();

String Scmd = (@"SELECT COUNT(poll_Name)FROM aspnet_Poll WHERE poll_Name='Good';");
String Scmd1 = (@"SELECT COUNT(poll_Name)FROM aspnet_Poll WHERE poll_Name='Excellent';");
String Scmd2 = (@"SELECT COUNT(poll_Name)FROM aspnet_Poll WHERE poll_Name='Acceptable';");
String Scmd3 = (@"SELECT COUNT(poll_Name)FROM aspnet_Poll WHERE poll_Name='I Dont Know';");
String Scmd4 = (@"SELECT COUNT(poll_Name)FROM aspnet_Poll;");


SqlDataReader dr0 =con.getDrPassSql(Scmd);
SqlDataReader dr1 = con1.getDrPassSql(Scmd1);
SqlDataReader dr2 = con22.getDrPassSql(Scmd2);
SqlDataReader dr3 = con3.getDrPassSql(Scmd3);
SqlDataReader dr4 = con3.getDrPassSql(Scmd4);


while (dr0.Read())
{Good=dr0.GetValue(0).ToString(); }
while (dr1.Read())
{ Excellent = dr1.GetValue(0).ToString(); }
while (dr2.Read())
{ Acceptable = dr2.GetValue(0).ToString(); }
while (dr3.Read())
{ Dont = dr3.GetValue(0).ToString(); }
while (dr4.Read())
{ total = dr4.GetValue(0).ToString(); }
```

code in ASP.net I use the count number to select width

```
 <div runat="server" id="radio2"> 
           
<!-- Green -->
  <asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$Resources: , Excellent %>" ></asp:Localize>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success " style="width: <%=Excellent%>%;"> <asp:Label ID="ex" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></div>
</div>

<!-- Turquoise -->
           <asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$Resources: , Good %>" ></asp:Localize>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-info" style="width: <%=Good%>%;"> <asp:Label ID="go" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></div>
</div>

<!-- Orange -->
           <asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$Resources: , Acceptable %>" ></asp:Localize>
<div class="progress">
   <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" style="width: <%=Acceptable%>%;"> <asp:Label ID="ac" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></div>
</div>

<!-- Red -->
          <asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$Resources: , Dont %>" ></asp:Localize>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" style="width: <%=Dont%>%;">  <asp:Label ID="do" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "efficient"? What concrete metric do you currently have and are targeting for the improvement?

Comment: Have you learned Group By in SQL? That sounds like what you want, if what you want is to combine all your queries into one.

Comment: yes but I don't know how can use it with SqlDataReader , how can i retrieve them ( SELECT COUNT(poll_Name),poll_Name
FROM aspnet_Poll
group by poll_Name order by poll_Name ASC; )

Comment: You'd then have 4 rows to read with 2 columns each.

Answer (score 1):

You are using query for every value of poll_Name it is not seem to be efficient.
But Recommend to use group by to fetch the records in single query.

```
select COUNT(poll_Name) as poll_count, poll_Name as poll_name  from aspnet_Poll group by poll_Name;
```

Where poll_Name is Good, Excellent, Acceptable and I Dont Know.

And you can use it in ASP like.

```
@foreach (var res in Result)
{
<asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$Resources: , @res %>" ></asp:Localize>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-success " style="width: <%=@res%>%;"> <asp:Label ID="ex" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label></div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Ok , how can i read it in asp each count in separate variables?